How to Extract the Actual Value from &8&P in VBA?
What I tried:
I attempted to retrieve the value from the RightHeader in VBA using the following code:
Sub GetRightHeaderValue()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    Dim headerValue As String
    headerValue = ws.PageSetup.RightHeader
    
    MsgBox "RightHeader Value: " & headerValue
End Sub

The MsgBox displayed &8&P, but this doesn't seem to be the actual data I need.
What I expected:
I expected the RightHeader to return the real, meaningful value, such as formatted text or numbers, rather than &8&P. I need help decoding or interpreting this output to retrieve the actual value.
RightHeader

AFAIK and I could be wrong but these dynamic formatting code used by Excel do not resolve to their final display values when accessed directly through VBA. Having said that if you have Adobe Acrobat then you can export the sheet as pdf to to a temp directory and then read the values of the right header from that.

Is it &8 (number eight) or &B (letter B) ?

If the header info is about total number of pages, you can use;
MsgBox Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")


I have set &[Page] in the right header in Page Setup to display the current page number. However, this value is dynamic and only visible in Print Preview. Is there a way to retrieve the current page number programmatically through VBA?

To get the number of pages of a worksheet (Activesheet as an example below) use
Activesheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count


Thank you for your response. However, this doesn't address my question. I am not looking for the total number of pages in the worksheet (ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count). Instead, I am trying to retrieve the current page number (&[Page]) programmatically through VBA. I understand this value is dynamic and only visible in Print Preview, but I would like to know if there's a way to access it directly in VBA. Could you provide guidance on this?"

You mean page number for a specific cell? If so, you can count vertical and horizontal page breaks and taking into account sheet order you can calculate this page number. You can find suitable code here: https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011581_Page_Numbers_in_VBA.html

@MGonet Well caught. Yesterday I searched for properties with "page" but missed Worksheet somehow.
